# nested recursive function in swift

Tags: ios, recursion, functional-programming, swift

I'm trying to do a nested recursive function but when I compile, the compiler crash (Segmentation fault).

Here is my code :

```
func test()
{
    func inner(val : Int)
    {
        println("\(val)")
        if val > 0
        {
           inner(val - 1)
        }
    }
    inner(3)
}
```

And the compiler logs [are here](http://pastebin.com/rBgtxuJv)

Comment: looks like a bug to me

Comment: Yes, file a bug report, compilers shouldn't crash :p

Comment: I know that the compiler shouldn't crash but as it's a beta, syntax errors can provoque this kind of error. My question is : is there any syntax error in my code ? Is there something like the `rec` keyword in OCaml ?

Comment: GOOD NEWS! it looks like this has been fixed in Swift2 - drop the original code (above) into a playground in Xcode 7 beta and call the `test()` function, works as expected!  :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

interesting... it seems like maybe it's bailing when trying to capture a reference to `inner` before it has been defined?

the following fixes it for us:

```
func test() {
    var inner: (Int) -> () = { _ in }    // give it a no-op definition
    inner = { val in
        println("\(val)")
        if val > 0 {
            inner(val - 1)
        }
    }
    inner(3)
}
```

of course without the nesting we don't have any issues at all, e.g. the following works completely as expected:

```
func test(val: Int) {
    println("\(val)")
    if val > 0 {
        test(val - 1)
    }
}
test(3)
```

I'd say: report it!

Comment: The fix is not really 'sexy' but it do the job waiting for an official fix. Thank !

Comment: When declaring arrays you can't mutate them inside this solution. How to declare them correctly?